# have used NSthreads,NSOperation,GCD and has used very less UI,I am getting receivedmemorywarning and app crashing

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have used NSthreads,NSOperation,GCD and has used very less UI,I am getting receivedmemorywarning and memory going above300MB with crashing the application,please suggest .Already made foundation objects nil after using and used autoreleasepool in side dispatch queue and for loops.

Comment: Its very hard to tell the reason behind memory warnings. There could be many reasons. Have you tried Instruments?

Comment: Hi Bharat,I used instruments,but could not identify the exact object by name or file which is responsible for memory leak.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Oritm,I am getting the memory issue throughout the application,even I am not getting which part of my code is responsible for it,Thanks.